# Javascript - How to call a second function

Tags: javascript, function

I have created two submit buttons, however I want the functions to run one after another.

When submit button clicked 
    run function validateBoxes 
when finished 
    run function validateBooking

I have pasted my code below. Newbie so would really appreciate the help. Thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Jet2it Booking Service</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateBoxes() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    if (document.Holiday.firstname.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter your firstname \n";
        document.Holiday.firstname.focus();
        document.getElementById('firstname').style.color = "red";
        result = false;
    }
    if (document.Holiday.secondname.value == "") {
        msg += "You must enter your secondname \n";
        document.Holiday.secondname.focus();
        document.getElementById('secondname').style.color = "red";
        result = false;
    }
    if (msg == "") {
        return result;
    }
    {
        alert(msg)
        return result;
    }
}

function validateBooking() {
    var result = true;
    var msg = "";
    var booking = "";
    if (Holiday.bookings[0].checked == true) {
        booking = "Italy";
    }
    if (Holiday.bookings[1].checked == true) {
        booking = "Malta";
    }
    if (Holiday.bookings[1].checked == true) {
        booking = "Portugal";
    }
    if (confirm("You have selected " + booking + ". Continue?")) {
        if (msg == "") {
            return result;
        }
        {
            alert(msg)
            return result;
        }
    }
    else {
        alert("booking Error");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="Holiday" method="post" action="confirmed.html">
<table width="50%" border="0">
<tr>
<td id="firstname">First firstname</td>
<td><input type="text" name="firstname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td id="secondname">Second name</td>
<td><input type="text" name="secondname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="bookings" value="Italy"/>
        Italy</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="bookings" value="Malta"/>
        Malta</label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>
        <input type="radio" name="bookings" value="Portugal"/>
         Portugal</label></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit_firstname_etc" 
value="Submit_firstname_etc" onClick="return validateBoxes();" /></td>           
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit_Destination" 
value="Submit_Destination"  onClick="return validateBooking();" /></td>
<td><input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please do people the courtesy of formatting your code legibly when asking for help. I've done it for you on this occasion. You'll also note that when you do that, you find that the code has blocks that serve no purpose (such as the block at the end of `validateBoxes`). I suspect you're missing some `else`s.

Answer (score 4):

Create a function that calls the two functions in the order you want, e.g. *something* like:

```
function validateBoth() {
    var result = validateBoxes();
    if (result) {
        result = validateBooking();
    }
    return result;
}
```

...and then use that function wherever it is that you want both functions to be used.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new function that encapsulates both functions and tie it to a button. If the function returns false, then it will not post to your confirmation page.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateBoth() {
    if (validateBoxes() && validateBooking()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Or you can get fancy with the code; this says the same thing as the previous code block. If both functions return true as a result, then validateBoth will return true; otherwise, validateBoth will return false.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function validateBoth() {
    return (validateBoxes() && validateBooking());
}
</script>
```

Then, somewhere in your form, you tie the validateBoth function to your button's onClick function:

```
<input type="submit" name="One Button" onClick="return validateBoth();" />
```